# R: how to use random forests to predict binary outcome using string variables?

Tags: r, machine-learning, classification, random-forest, text-classification

Consider the following dataframe

```
outcome <- c(1,0,0,1,1)
string <- c('I love pasta','hello world', '1+1 = 2','pasta madness', 'pizza madness')

df = df=data.frame(outcome,string)


> df
  outcome        string
1       1  I love pasta
2       0   hello world
3       0       1+1 = 2
4       1 pasta madness
5       1 pizza madness
```

Here I would like to use random forests to understand which words in the sentences contained in the `string` variable are **strong predictors** of the `outcome` variable.

Is there a (simple) way to do that in R?

Comment: You will probably need quite a lot of text preprocessing, e.g. for all pasta and pizza related texts you can create a binary column "is_food" and voila, 100% accuracy (of course this is an extremely simplified example).

Comment: thanks! but i actually dont need pre processing. I am just interested in the forecasting power of single words, such as pizza, pasta etc

Comment: Split by space, transform into columns then indicators, run rf?

Comment: interesting. do you know how to code that up in the example above?

Comment: @Noobie, I am still convinced you need some preprocessing like removing the stop words, converting other words to their roots (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Root_(linguistics)) etc.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What you want is the variable importance measures as produced by `randomForest`. This is obtained from the `importance` function. Here is some code that should get you started:

```
outcome <- c(1,0,0,1,1)
string <- c('I love pasta','hello world', '1+1 = 2','pasta madness', 'pizza madness')
```

**Step 1:** We want `outcome` to be a factor so that `randomForest` will do **classification** and `string` as character vectors.

```
df <- data.frame(outcome=factor(outcome,levels=c(0,1)),string, stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
```

**Step 2:** Tokenize the `string` column into words. Here, I'm using `dplyr` and `tidyr` just for convenience. The key is to have just word tokens that you want as your predictor variable.

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
inp <- df %>% mutate(string=strsplit(string,split=" ")) %>% unnest(string)
##   outcome  string
##1        1       I
##2        1    love
##3        1   pasta
##4        0   hello
##5        0   world
##6        0     1+1
##7        0       =
##8        0       2
##9        1   pasta
##10       1 madness
##11       1   pizza
##12       1 madness
```

**Step 3:** Construct a model matrix and feed it to `randomForest`:

```
library(randomForest)
mm <- model.matrix(outcome~string,inp)
rf <- randomForest(mm, inp$outcome, importance=TRUE)
imp <- importance(rf)
##                     0        1 MeanDecreaseAccuracy MeanDecreaseGini
##(Intercept)   0.000000 0.000000             0.000000        0.0000000
##string1+1     0.000000 0.000000             0.000000        0.3802400
##string2       0.000000 0.000000             0.000000        0.4514319
##stringhello   0.000000 0.000000             0.000000        0.4152465
##stringI       0.000000 0.000000             0.000000        0.2947108
##stringlove    0.000000 0.000000             0.000000        0.2944955
##stringmadness 4.811252 5.449195             5.610477        0.5733814
##stringpasta   4.759957 5.281133             5.368852        0.6651675
##stringpizza   0.000000 0.000000             0.000000        0.3025495
##stringworld   0.000000 0.000000             0.000000        0.4183821
```

As you can see, pasta and madness are key words to predict the `outcome`.

**Please Note:** There are many parameters to `randomForest` that will be relevant for tackling the real-problem of scale. This is by no means a complete solution to your problem. It is only meant to illustrate the use of the `importance` function in answering your question. You may want to ask appropriate questions on [Cross Validated](http://stats.stackexchange.com) concerning the details of using `randomForest`.

Comment: in your experience, does this algo works nice with very large and sparse matrices ( a lot of words, but many of them have 1 or 2 occurrences)

Comment: @Noobie: what will happen there is that your input to random forest will have a lot of predictors since the model matrix, which is a contrast matrix of your words in `string`, will have a lot of columns. Random forest scales well to number of predictors, but as with anything parallelization is required for truly large problems. A better alternative may be `xgboost`, which also has an `importance` capability.

Comment: @Noobie: one other point. For really large and sparse model matrices, you may want/need to use `sparse.model.matrix` from the `Matrix` package. Unfortunately, I don't believe `randomForest` supports a sparse matrix input, so that is a limitation. However, `xgboost` does and you can use its `importance` function to do the same analysis. So, I would suggest you try `xgboost`.